# Deducing two points are topologically indistinguishable by sub-base

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, separation-axioms

I have the following argument which I would like to verify:

> Let $X$ be a topological space with a sub-base $\{ S_\alpha \}_\alpha$ such that $\cup S_\alpha\neq X$. Then every $x,y\in X\setminus \cup S_\alpha$ are topologically indistinguishable.

And when I say topologically indistinguishable, I mean that for any open set $U$, $x,y\in U$ or $x,y\notin U$. My argument goes as follows:

Conisder the collection $\mathcal{S}:=\{ S_\alpha \}_\alpha \cup\{ X\}$. Then it generates a basis $\mathcal{B}$ whose elements are finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal{S}$. For any $x,y\in X\setminus \cup S_\alpha$ be distinct points, the only open set which contains $x$ or $y$ has to be $X$. Let $B\in \mathcal{B}$, i.e.:

$$ B=\cap_{i=1}^n S_{\alpha_i} $$

If $x\in B$, then $x\in S_{\alpha_i}$ for all $i\in [n]$, and hence $S_{\alpha_i}=X$ for all $i\in [n]$, and $B=X$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, any open set containing $x$ must be the whole space $X$. And similarly for $y$.

This would imply that if a topological space has a sub-base which is not a cover, then it can not be a $T_0$ space. Is this reasoning sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more direct argument, avoiding your enlarged $\mathcal{S}$: So for me $\mathcal{S}$ is the given subbase for the topology on $X$, and now suppose $x \in X\setminus \bigcup \mathcal{S}$ and suppose $B$ is a basic open set that contains $x$. By definition the subbase consists of the set of **all** finite intersections from $\mathcal{S}$ and so $B=\bigcap \mathcal{S}'$ where $\mathcal{S}' \subseteq \mathcal{S}$ is finite. If $\mathcal{S}'$ were non-empty, say we have some $S \in \mathcal{S}'$, then $x \in S$, contradicting its choice outside the union. So $\mathcal{S'}=\emptyset$ and so
$B= \bigcap \mathcal{S'}=X$. So $X$ is the *only* open neighbourhood of $x$.

So if the union misses more than one point, the resulting space is not $T_0$. Otherwise it will depend on the other subbase elements. E.g. Sierpiński space is $T_0$ and has subbase $\{0\}$ on the set $\{0,1\}$. The empty subbase always yields the indiscrete topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$.

Comment: So my proof is okay, right?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur No, not really. Why can you add $X$? That needs an argument too.  And the conclusion was wrong (Sierpinski space showed that): you need *two* points outside the union.

Comment: I see now that my conclusion was hasty, but saying that you can add $X$ is just using the second definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes, if that is your (wrong) definition, go ahead. The first one is the one normally used (in papers etc.), the second one is a Munkres-introduced deviation that somehow made it into Wikipedia...

Comment: Is it still equivalent to definition of a sub-base though? Despite not being the proper definition?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur it gives the same topology. So yes in that sense.